# Accessing another class' method from within a standalone function

Tags: php, class, object, methods

I am converting a my site to PDO and after about 200 scripts I am very near the end. Every script accesses the same functions script. Within the functions script I have a Database class which looks like so:

```
class Database {
    private $db_con = ''; //stores the connection

    public function db_login(){
        //log into the database
    }
    public function db_control($query, $params){
        //run the query
    }
}
//initiate the class and log in
$db = new Database();
$db->db_login();
```

Both of these functions work fine and for every type of query, hence why I am almost finished. However, I have run into a problem.

I have a standalone function on a script I am working on which is used several times within the script. I usually run the db_control:

```
$results = $db->db_control($query, $params);
```

But running it from within a function:

```
function func(){
    $results = $db->db_control($query, $params);
}
```

Returns the error.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function db_control() on a non-object in
>   C:....php on line 39

What am I doing wrong? The class is definitely being initiated as other queries on the script work fine when this function is removed. How can I access db_control() from within a standalone function?

Thank you,
Joe

Comment: Method one: pass `$db` into the function as a parameter; Method two: use `global $db;` inside the function. Method one might be "recommended" in many context, but you'll have to modify every place that calls it; method two is less "elegant", but you just need to modify once (as long as you don't rename `$db`).

Comment: What you're doing is hardly OOP. See [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/) for some pointers.

Comment: Yes I know. To convert the entire site to OOP is not top priority right now as the site has not launched and I am living off a few bob a week. Once the site is operational and an income has been acquired the site shall be fully converted to OOP. For now, if I can assist future me by making certain aspects OOP'ish then that shall do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$db` is not available within the function scope, you could

Pass `$db` as an argument

```
function func($db, $query, $params){
    return $db->db_control($query, $params);
}
$results = func($db, $query, $params);
```

Or

```
function func($query, $params){
    global $db;
    return $db->db_control($query, $params);
}
$result = func($query, $params);
```

Use `global` to make it available within the function, there's probably other solutions too!

Comment: Thanks! I thought it was that. My brain isn't functioning properly this morning! Aha.

Answer (score 1):

`$db` is out of scope when called from within a function. You could pass `$db` to the function as an argument

```
function func($db){
```

There is also the horribly bad `global` method:

```
function func(){
    global $db; // $db is now accessible
```

Answer (score 1):

Learn about [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). The variable `$db` is not declared inside the function, so it does not exist inside the function. You need to pass it in.

Comment: Thanks for the link you left in the comment. Very interesting read. The site shall one day operate like that.

Answer (score 1):

Oooh, you have initiated $db as a global :/

There are a lot of reasons why you would not want to do this and I will not go into this here primarily because I am a tad short on time, I will await the purists to comment below. But a quick fix is to add.

```
global $db
```

Not the most ideal situation ever but should solve your issue.

Comment: Sorry a sentence got cutoff, add the global declaration within your function.