# PDO Prepare() function Fatal error:

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i am actually started using PDO , i have seen many questions on PDO but i am not able resolve my problem by reading those questions.

I have one file PDO Config File called `db.php` , this file having no problem.

```
db.php 

<?php 
######## PDO Config File ##########
        $mysql_hostname = "localhost";
        $mysql_user = "web";
        $mysql_password = "123123";
        $mysql_database = "123123";
        //$odb = new PDO ("mysql:host=".$mysql_hostname.";dbname=".$mysql_database;charset:UTF-8",$mysql_user,$mysql_password);
        try{
                $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=".$mysql_hostname.";dbname=".$mysql_database.";charset:UTF-8", $mysql_user, $mysql_password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
        }
        catch(PDOException $pe){
            die('Could connect to the database because: ' .$pe->getMessage());
        }
 ?>
```

I have Included this file in to the following PHP file[setting.php] .

```
setting.php

class Account
{
    public function userEmailChnage($inputCurrentEmail,$inputChangeEmail,$inputConfirmEmail)
    {
        if(!empty($inputCurrentEmail) AND !empty($inputChangeEmail) AND !empty($inputConfirmEmail)){
            $selectEmail        = "select mail from users where mail = ?";
            $selectEmailPrepare = $connect -> prepare($selectEmail);
            $selectEmailPrepare -> execute(array($inputConfirmEmail));

        if ($selectEmailPrepare ->rowCoun() > 0 ) {     
                if($inputChangeEmail == $inputConfirmEmail) {
                        $EmailUpdate = "UPDATE users SET mail= ?";
                        $EmailUpdatePrepare = $connect->prepare($EmailUpdate);
                        $EmailUpdatePrepare -> execute(array($inputChangeEmail));
                        $msg[EmailUpdateOpration]=Success;

                }else{
                        $msg[IsConfirmMailMatching]=FALSE; //---------------- > JSON ERROR Msg 
                }
            }else{
                    $msg[IsEmailInDatabase]=FALSE; //---------------- > JSON ERROR Msg 
            }
        }else{
            $msg[IsEmailFieldEmpty]=TRUE; //---------------- > JSON ERROR Msg 
        }   
        header("Content-Type: application/json", true); 
        echo json_encode($msg); 
    }

}
```

After the execution of the file i am facing following error :

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/admin/public_html/class/setting.php on line 12
```

I am tried to change PDO config file , it didn't worked. I started testing setting.php .. Not able to solve it !

Comment: `$connect` must be a `PDO` object before you can use it inside of `userEmailChnage()` function. nitpick.. please correct `userEmailChnage` into `userEmailChange` to avoid confusing the function spelling.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing another class' method from within a standalone function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932191/accessing-another-class-method-from-within-a-standalone-function)

Comment: I have included that file into setting.php so it is object !

Comment: Learn about [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)!

Comment: Also, are `EmailUpdateOpration`, `Success` etc. constants? If not: **quote them**. Turn on error reporting and you'll see lots of warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
$EmailUpdatePrepare = $connect->prepare($EmailUpdate);
```

... you get this error:

> Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

That means exactly that: `$connect` is *not* an object. It appears to be a global variable so you need to handle it as such: either call `global $connect;` before you use it or read it through `$GLOBALS['connect']`. (Or, even better, pass it as argument to the method.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `$connect` is not an object of PDO. It's probably some NULL or false value.
Probably your connection failed silently. Try checking for thrown PDOException:

```
try {
    // pdo connection
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    exit($e->getMessage());
}
```

notice that the `PDO::__construct()` return an object only on success, and it thows an exception otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You should include/require db.php in userEmailChnage() method.

Comment: Would rather pass a reference to a member variable of the Account class and use this reference inside the class.